# Will other actions interrupt digging?

Tags: the-gold-factory

After digging to the training building, I found that I can dig into the wall.  The game says:

> You are currently digging
>   Time left: 30 minute(s) remaining

It gives the option to close the window as well.  Can I close the window and do other things or will that interrupt the digging?  If it does interrupt, will it restart from 30 minutes or pick up where left off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not interrupt. You can go do other things and come back to check if it has finished.

Comment: So you can close the browser and come back 30 minutes later?  Given that this is Javascript, that means you could also just close the browser, set your computer's clock ahead 30 minutes *(make sure to disable auto-sync)*, and open it back up again.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft:No, the game can't be "fooled" by that method